# android app socket.io not connecting to node.js server but android browser makes connection

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have setup node.js server running on port 3000. Connections from my laptop browser are successful and I can see the result in the console log.

In my android client I used [nkzawa's](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) Socket.io library, but it's not establishing connection with the server, where as when I try to open the http://i.p.addr:PORT, in my android browser, connection is successful.

To be sure, I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a public DNS for my localhost:PORT. When i use ngrok's public DNS for Socket connection, android throws an error saying Internet permission denied and unable to resolve hostname. (Is it because of redirects?) but that address works fine on laptop and mobile browser.

I am completely stuck here. Android Socket.io is not connecting to server. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFfd4QbmWpI). What am I missing?

**Server:**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  


 connections =[];

 server.listen(3000);
 console.log("server running ...");

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });

 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log("new connection");
    console.log('connected: %s sockets', connections.length);

    // Disconeect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket),1);
        console.log('Disconnection');
        console.log('connected: %s sockets', connections.length);
    }); 

  });
```

**Android Client:**

```
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  static  final String TAG = "MainActivity" ;
    private Socket mSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting socket connection");
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://10.10.11.44:3000/");
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR : Socket connection failed");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        mSocket.connect();
        if(mSocket.connected()){
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket connection successful");
        }
        else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket connection failed");
        }

    }
  .
  .
  .
```

**Android client Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.batmanlost.chatapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Its too late for reply but Can you please replace this "http://10.10.11.44:3000/" by "http://i.p.addr:3000" in android app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator for testing purpose then use localhost address as 'http://10.0.2.2:3000'
and if you are using your mobile device for testing then you need to connect your mobile phone with the same network on which you pc/laptop is connected and then use the same address given above for connection.